# Run Python script from cmd in windows

Tags: python, python-2.7, crf++

I need to generate features from text. The script I am using below is available online but actually I do not know how to run it because I do not know python at all.
I have a text file called (train.txt) contains the following

```
He PRP B-NP
reckons VBZ B-VP
the DT B-NP
current JJ I-NP
account NN I-NP
deficit NN I-NP
will MD B-VP
narrow VB I-VP
to TO B-PP
only RB B-NP
# # I-NP
1.8 CD I-NP
billion CD I-NP
in IN B-PP
September NNP B-NP
. . O
```

and I have a python script that convert the above text to features like the following features:

```
B-NP    w[0]=He w[1]=reckons    w[2]=the        w[0]|w[1]=He|reckons    pos[0]=P
RP      pos[1]=VBZ      pos[2]=DT       pos[0]|pos[1]=PRP|VBZ   pos[1]|pos[2]=VB
Z|DT    pos[0]|pos[1]|pos[2]=PRP|VBZ|DT __BOS__
...
```

The python script is

```
# Separator of field values.
separator = ' '

# Field names of the input data.
fields = 'w pos y'

# Attribute templates.
templates = (
    (('w', -2), ),
    (('w', -1), ),
    (('w',  0), ),
    (('w',  1), ),
    (('w',  2), ),
    (('w', -1), ('w',  0)),
    (('w',  0), ('w',  1)),
    (('pos', -2), ),
    (('pos', -1), ),
    (('pos',  0), ),
    (('pos',  1), ),
    (('pos',  2), ),
    (('pos', -2), ('pos', -1)),
    (('pos', -1), ('pos',  0)),
    (('pos',  0), ('pos',  1)),
    (('pos',  1), ('pos',  2)),
    (('pos', -2), ('pos', -1), ('pos',  0)),
    (('pos', -1), ('pos',  0), ('pos',  1)),
    (('pos',  0), ('pos',  1), ('pos',  2)),
    )


import crfutils

def feature_extractor(X):
    # Apply attribute templates to obtain features (in fact, attributes)
    crfutils.apply_templates(X, templates)
    if X:
    # Append BOS and EOS features manually
        X[0]['F'].append('__BOS__')     # BOS feature
        X[-1]['F'].append('__EOS__')    # EOS feature

if __name__ == '__main__':
    crfutils.main(feature_extractor, fields=fields, sep=separator)
```

Both script.py and crfutils.py exist in the same folder 
I run the above script from cmd on Windows 7 as follow:

```
C:\>Python script.py train.txt > train.result.txt
```

I've got an empty file titled train.result.txt
and because I am new to python (actually just start learning it). I do not know what is the problem? am I providing the arguments in a wrong order? Is the format of the train.txt file wrong?

Comment: What does:  python script.py train.txt return to the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass in train.txt on stdin, not as a command line argument:

```
C:\>Python script.py < train.txt > train.result.txt
```

Comment: I tried that ,the train.result.txt is successfully created but is empty!!

Comment: OK, I worked through it. The key is that you need an empty line on the end of your train.txt file (and you need to call it as I gave above). The read_iter() function in crfutils.py only returns the iterator if it reaches a blank line.

Comment: (and when I do that I get a result exactly like the one you give in the question)

Comment: @Wahedsaw - just realised I'm not sure you get a ping when I comment (as opposed to answer). So pinging you here to look at my above comment where I have explained the answer for you.